# ReactJS - Can't get function to load values from separate file after refactoring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

After attempting to factor out functions within my App class in React into separate files, I am dealing with a whirlwind of import/export issues and was wondering if I could get some advice:

First, is factoring out functions from classes within other files/classes a logical thing to do?

Second, this is a specific problem that I'm having:

**Expected Behavior:**  The function MainTable.tableGen() should return a value which App's render() can process.

**Actual Behavior:** Stepping through the debugger shows that tableGen() is not being fired, but it is recognized.  In other words, it is not running the function and returning the value but returning the function as it's printed.

Main.js:

```
import MainTable from './app/components/input_table/maintable';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      this.MainTable = this.MainTable.bind(this);
}

MainTable(){
MainTable.tableGen();  //Call the function that's in the external file here
}
render(){
        return (
          <div>
          <table>
          <tbody onLoad = {this.broadcast()}>  
            {this.MainTable}  //The MainTable.tableGen() function populates the table using a series of loops 
          </tbody>
          </table>
          <ButtonMenu onRow = {this.onRowButton} onCol = {this.onColumnButton} undo ={this.onUndoAction} redo = {this.onRedoAction} reset = {this.onResetAction} />
          </div>

        );
      }

}
```

maintable.js:

```
class baseTable extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    //properties
    super(props);
  }

 tableGen(){


... function code here...

}
const MainTable = new baseTable; 

export default MainTable;
```

Comment: `The function MainTable.tableGen() should return a value which App's render() can process.` To me that sounds like you should create a separate component that you can reuse in `MainTable` and `BaseTable` instead.

Comment: tableGen() returns an array of JSX values to be rendered.  The problem is that I don't think the code is even running through the function to get that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `tableGen()` returns JSX, without quote.

```
return <h3>Hello World</h3>;
```

Then, your MainTable function should have `return` keyword:

```
MainTable() {
  return MainTable.tableGen();
}
```

And, invoke the function when referencing it in JSX:

```
{this.MainTable()}
```